# Hive - Issue with the hive sub query

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql, hue

My problem statement is like

"Find top 2 districts per state with the highest population"

data is like

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViFUa.png)

My expected output is

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO8qZ.png)

I tried this with lot of queries and sub-queries but results in SQL error with the sub query

Can anyone help me with getting this result?

Thanks in advance.

Queries I tried

1. Select 
   state_name, 
   (select concat_ws(',', collect_set(dist_name as string)) from population where state_name = state_name group by state order by population desc 2)

from population group by state_name

2. select
   state_name, 
   concat_ws(',', collect_set(cast(dist_name as string)))
   from population
   where population.dist_name in (select dist_name from (
   select dist_name , max(b.population) as total
   from population b
   where state_name = b.state_name
   group by b.dist_name , b.dist_name 
   order by total desc limit 2) 
   as dist_name )
   group by state_name

Comment: It is better to post the text here, than in images. Also you must show us what you have done so far. The queries that you have tried.

Comment: Can you post what queries did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query -

```
 select A.state, collect_set(A.dist)[0], collect_set(A.dist)[1] from 
(select state, dist, row_number() over (partition by state order by population 
 desc) as rnk from <tableName>) A
where A.rnk<=2 group by A.state;
```

Below are the results for sample data -

```
hive> select * from hier;
OK
C1      C11
C11     C12
C12     123
P1      C1
P2      C2

hive> select parent, collect_set(child)[0], collect_set(child)[1] from hier group by parent;
OK
C1      C11     NULL
C11     C12     NULL
C12     123     NULL
P1      C1      NULL
P2      C2      NULL
Time taken: 19.212 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Comment: Facing this error "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rnk' '<=' in subquery source"

Comment: Please use the updated query, i missed the alias initially